# Sitecore versioned image not loading

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I'm running Sitecore 6.5 and have a data template that has an image field and an item that's based on that template. The site had two languages.

If I use a versioned image (one item in the media library with En and Fr versions) in the En and Fr versions of the item then publish the site and switch the language in the site using query string, sc_lang=en or fr, everything changes in the page except for the image.

But if I use two different images (two items in the media library) then the correct image loads when switching between languages.

Any idea to why this happens?

Thanks
T

**Update**

I tried using the shared option and that didn't work.  I also noticed that if I just add the query parameter and hit enter, the page changes to correct language but the image doesn't until I hit the refresh button. It seems a caching issue but why does it happen only with versioned images.

Comment: Is your image field on the data template set to 'shared'?

Comment: I've tried the shared option and that didn't work either

Comment: Are you using a <SC:Image control to render the image field?

Comment: Yes, I also tried FieldRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore support confirmed that it is a bug and here's their temporary workaround:

1. Copy `Sitecore.Support.320556.dll` to the `website\bin` folder, the dll isn't on SDN yet, http://tareknasser.com/projects/sitecore/Sitecore.Support.320556.dll
2. In the web.config file find and comment out the following node:

> ```
> <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
> ```

and add the following one below right after the commented one:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Support.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Support.320556"/>
```

That worked for me in both the publish site and the page editor.

Comment: Updated the dll as I found another bug with it and Sitecore support provided another dll to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a bug with the `<sc:image />` and `FieldRenderer` controls in that the generated URL doesn't have a language in the querystring.

You can try something like this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="image" runat="server"><img src="{0}" /></asp:Literal>

Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions
{
    Language = Sitecore.Context.Language
};
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Image"];
string url = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem, options);
image.Text = string.Format(image.Text, url);
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, the solution works for displaying the image but doesn't support page editor anymore as a SC image or field renderer would. I searched SDN and didn't come across this bug, is it referenced somewhere? Can you provide the link for it, please?

Comment: I think it was just discovered ;) You may want to report this to Sitecore support and see what they say.

Comment: @ErgonomicDeveloper, I would encourage you to contact Sitecore support on this. Your report will help making Sitecore CMS even better! :-)

Comment: Submitted the issue to Sitecore's support, I'll post an update once I get more info from them.